# Exception handling in aws-lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dns, aws-lambda

While trying to implement a `DNSRequest`, I also needed to do some exception handling and noticed something weird. The following code is able to catch DNS request **timeouts**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    hostname = "google.de"
    dnsIpAddresses = event['dnsIpAddresses']
    dnsResolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    dnsResolver.lifetime = 1.0
    result = {}

    for dnsIpAddress in dnsIpAddresses:
        dnsResolver.nameservers = [dnsIpAddress]

        try:
           myAnswers = dnsResolver.query(hostname, "A")
           print(myAnswers)
           result[dnsIpAddress] = "SUCCESS"
        except dns.resolver.Timeout:
           print("caught Timeout exception")
           result[dnsIpAddress] = "FAILURE"
        except dns.exception.DNSException:
           print("caught DNSException exception")
           result[dnsIpAddress] = "FAILURE"
        except:
           result[dnsIpAddress] = "FAILURE"
           print("caught general exception")

    return result
```

Now, if I removed the Timeout block, and assuming that a Timeout would occur, on a DNSException the message

> caught DNSException exception

will never be shown.

Now, if I removed the DNSException block, and assuming that a Timeout would occur, the message

> caught general exception

will never be shown.

But the Timeout extends the DNSException and the DNSException extends Exception. I had the expectation that at least the general expect block should work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your last block try making the `print` line come before `result[dnsIpAddress] = "FAILURE"`
My guess is either there is more code than what is shown here or the line before the print statement causes a different exception.